# Missing application resource

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

**Use java to write the spark program, the code is as follows:**

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

public class SimpleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("wordCount").setMaster("local"); 
      JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf); 
      JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile("/bigdata/softwares/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/testdata/a.txt");
      System.out.println();
      Long bCount = input.filter(new Function<String,Boolean>(){
         public Boolean call(String s){return s.contains("yes");}
      }).count();
      Long cCount = input.filter(new Function<String,Boolean>(){
         public Boolean call(String s){return s.contains("ywq");}
      }).count();
      System.out.println("yes:"+bCount+"  ywq:"+cCount+"  all：");
//    sc.stop();
  }
}
```

**Pom as follows：**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>      
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

**The following error occurred**
**Maven all the resources are packaged into jar file, run the time reported the following mistakes, I just started learning, who knows to teach, thank you**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You also have to specify your main class with spark-submit

```
spark-submit --class <your.package>.SimpleApp testjar/spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the main class along with master

```
./bin/spark-submit --class package.name.MainClass --master local[2] /testjar/spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```